# Как реализовать события?

Tags: события, delphi

Есть картинка 'карта' - программно прорисованная дорога. Если  кликнуть по дороге, то произойдет какое-то событие. Вопрос: как мне реализовать это?

Как можно программно создать линию, которая будет реагировать на события? Есть ли какой то объект с похожими свойствами?

---

Нашел ответ - [Obedient lines](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/sources/graph/2006_year/obedient_lines.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем виде решение такое.

Создаете класс или запись для хранения линий дорог в удобном вам виде.
Что-то вроде:

```
type
  TRoad = record
    From : TPoint;
    To: TPoint;
  end;
```

Храните где-нибудь ваши дороги (массив, список, итп.). Рисуете линии на канве. По клику по канве берете координаты точки и определяете, не принадлежат ли они к одной из линий.

Если принадлежат - обрабатываете это как-вам нужно (например, меняете цвет линии; для этого нужно добавить в TRoad еще и цвет).

Ну, а потом оптимизация отрисовки и обработки всего этого дела, отсечение невидимых линий, возможно, объединение линий в граф, поиск путей. В общем, смотря какая у вас там задача ).

Вам могут потребоваться определенные знания алгебры, геометрии и машинной графики. Ну и [Algolist](http://algolist.ru/) вам в помощь.

Comment: а как линия среагирует например на onClick

Comment: На OnClick среагирует компонент где будет происходить прорисовка, а вот в этом обработчике уже и нужно по текущему положению курсора определять есть ли под ним линия и, если есть, вызывать обработчик пользовательского события.

Comment: @KiTE, воистину так.